# Constructing a valid JSON object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-closure

I'm using the code below to construct a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"contacts":[{"provider":"Yahoo","firstName":"myname","lastName":"surname","nickname":"mynick","email":"myemail@hotmail.com","photoURL":"http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/social/profile/profile_bxx.png"}]};

var data = {};
var contacts;
var gc = $.when(gigya.socialize.getContacts({callback: function(response){
  data['contacts'] = response.contacts.asArray();
}}));
gc.done(function(response) {
  contacts = data;
});
console.log(contacts);
```

When I pass the resulting contacts object to Google soy template, the JSON object doesn't seem well constructed.

With the code above, how do I construct a valid JSON object?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: `getContacts()` is probably asynchronous, which would mean it's trying to log `contacts` before `contacts = data` is evaluated. Try moving `console.log(contacts)` into the `.done()` callback. For more info with a similar sample, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321.

Comment: I can get the value of `contacts` outside of `.done()`. The problem is with getting a valid JSON output

Comment: `var asJSON =`[`JSON.stringify(contacts)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: You don't need `$.when` here. Just use `gc = gigya.socialize.getContacts(...); gc.done(...);`.

Comment: @drecute: Why are you using the promise pattern then?

Comment: @Bergi Because I need access to `contacts` outside of the async callback.

Comment: @drecute: That's impossible. Promises are still asynchronous. Everything that depends on them must be another promise.

Answer (score 0):

The object seems ok,

try using `JOSN.stringify()` example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/errE5/)
or `JSON.parse()`

You can see in example, you can turn object into valid JSON and reverse into valid JS object.

---

Regarding your code

1. What do you get from `response` ?
2. And why do you use `response` here if you do not make use of it?

   ```
   gc.done(function(response) {
     contacts = data;
   });
   ```

---

I would change this line **EDITED**

```
data['contacts'] = response.contacts.asArray();
```

to

```
contacts = JSON.parse(response.contacts);
```

and remove

```
gc.done(function(response) {
  contacts = data;
});
```